# Nginx proxy with Docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker

This is my docker infra.

nginx webserver serving on port 80 (exposed to host)

media and blog serving on port 80 (not exposed to host) running under individual container

All running on the same VM.

---

```
        Name                      Command               State         Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
media                  docker-php-entrypoint apac ...   Up      80/tcp
mysql_db_blog          docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp
mysql_db_media         docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp
webserver              nginx -g daemon off;             Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
blog                   docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up      80/tcp
```

---

My nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name 192.168.0.7;
        server_tokens off;

        location /story/ {
            proxy_pass         http://blog/;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /videos/ {
            proxy_pass         http://media/;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
}
```

---

My issue:

When I try to access any of the below URLs

> 1) http://webserver/story
>
> 2) http://webserver/videos

after the first request, the last part 'story' or 'videos' gets deleted form the url.

What am I missing from nginx conf to make sure 'story' or 'videos' doesn't gets removed from the url?

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with how `proxy_pass` is written in your stanza.

From [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

```
location /name/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
}
```

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

So change your proxy_pass:

```
location /videos/ {
    proxy_pass         http://media;
```

Note - lack of trailing slash, means it preserves the original URI.

You might also want to look at `rewrite` as that does something related.